# Error loading USE or USELSX module: *javacon

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have one Notes client that gets this message multiple times everytime opening a view.
Notes client is version 9 swedish and it has just  been installed into a new computer.

The view do contain calls to Scriptlibraries and maybe also to some java code from complied code, (swingsoftware)

The strange thing is that the views work fine on all other computers running the same windows and Notes versions.

The obvious answer here would be to reinstall the client but that is not currently an option.

Looking in the java console I can see references to security errors. ( see image )

anyone have any tips for resolving this issue?

[image]

[image]

[!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaYYt.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaYYt.png)

Comment: Perhaps the one machine is running a different flavor of the client?  Or the others have a fixpack installed that this one doesn't?

Comment: it obviously dies while checking access rights. So maybe just give full access in java.policy file? Or try figure exactly what it fails to access.

Comment: Reinstalled Notes. Works now!